# - one user not able to get audio, but can see video

Tags: restcomm

I have searched for any previous questions and answers about this but i couldn't find any relevant info hence this question.
Just recently we have created WebRTC feature in our application by reusing most of the OLYMPUS code itself.
Also we have installed CA approved SSL Certs and all is well and we are able to get it working. But one strange thing is that one of the user is not able to hear any thing.  We have tried it multiple times with multiples users and laptops thinking that it could some issue with the laptop audio settings.
But consistently we notice that when we load the ROOM.HTML, both CALLER and CALLEE are able to see local and remote videso,and one of the user can even hear the audio but the other user will not hear any Audio.

First we faced this issue with one user, but thought it could laptop audio settings. So we tried with another user and the problem remains same.  I have double checked that we have not made any changes to the CALL configuration settings and it is exactly as per OLYMPUS code.

Can i request any suggestion on this pls.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So the Olympus web app works, while your doesn't? Or both have the same issue? Moreover, could you share the browser console output for the failed scenario, as well as the restcomm and media server logs?

Comment: Yes just now we have tested OLYMPUS and it is still the same issue. So the isse is for both our custom app and olympus too.  We have the browser console for both Alice and Bob and media server logs too.  But what is the preferred approach for me to share those files pls.

Comment: You can share using whichever tool you like, pastebin, gist, etc

Comment: OK here is the Media server log file via GIST   https://gist.github.com/Prefer2Watch/d02f9db317406d0ef130

Comment: Here is the Browser Console for ALICE   https://gist.github.com/Prefer2Watch/91f1ce5f7e5e09565390                                           and Here is the Browser console for BOB https://gist.github.com/Prefer2Watch/022eca4165cc9bf8c13d

Comment: As i mentioned we tried the standard ALICE and BOB call on OLYMPUS and same Audio problem we abvoe.  ABove i have shared Browser console for ALICE and BOB for this failed scenario along with Media server log ....via GIST.....as always thx in advance

Comment: HI  we are able to nail down this failure scenario  of (Audio not coming for one of the user) to one laptop being HP ENVY dv6 windows v8.1 OS. When one of the user uses this laptop then the other user can't get hear the audio, but the user using this laptop gets audio but there is no issue with Video.   But  when we use other laptop then audio isse is not coming.  I am wondering it could be some thing specific to do with this laptop or audio drivers or audio codes issue with this specific laptop.

Comment: Seems the most reasonable explanation Ias M. I mean logs both for caller and callee seem ok, and just realized this is a Peer to Peer scenario so Media Server doesn't get in the middle. You could check Chrome's chrome://webrtc-internals/ page in the problematic machine when you make the call and open the tab describing the call (entitled something like http://<ip>/olympus/*) and look for section 'ssrc_*_send' and then check for bytesSent and packetsSent to see if the media seems to be flowing ok towards the peer